# Is it possible to type check normalised arguments?

Tags: typescript

Let's suppose I have the following function signature:

```
function someFunction(arg1?: number, arg2?: string, arg3?: string|string[]) {}
```

where every argument is optional, so it should be called as

```
someFunction(undefined, undefined, [''])
```

if I want to omit some of them.

Now, using a library like [Node-NormalizeArguments](https://github.com/Carrooi/Node-NormalizeArguments), I may wrap this function in the following way:

```
function wrappedFunction() {
  const normalizedArgs = args(arguments, [
    args.number(undefined), 
    args.string(undefined),
    args.oneOf([
      args.array,
      args.string
    ], undefined)
  ]);
  return someFunction(...normalizedArgs)
}
```

and thus allow calling it as

```
someFunction([''])
```

to get the same result.

Of course there are drawbacks already (I lose the `string[]` type check by using args.array), but these may be fixed in the library code. The real question is:

How can I define the type of this new wrapped function? (preferably without verbosely listing all possible combinations of arguments or at least not doing it by hand)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand how the normalization works to allow `someFunction([''])` (I did see, though, that the library is no longer maintained). Is it guessing which of the arguments has been passed based on the type? Can it be generalized, if you have more than one argument with the same type? Might it make more sense to take a single `options` object instead, if the arguments are all optional and order is irrelevant?

Comment: "if you have more than one argument with the same type?" -- if you mean "sequentially", in this case they would be filled from input arguments from left to right. these are edge cases though.

Comment: "Might it make more sense to take a single options object instead" -- Absolutely. The problem though is that we already have users who rely on this syntax with normalised function parameters and we want to provide them with TypeScript typings before we start reworking the framework and making such breaking changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a bunch of type aliases to generate a set of overload signatures with all subsets of parameters:

```
// `CAaOb`: first `a` parameters are already assigned, remaining `b` are
// optional.  `X` is the union of the types of the optional parameters following
// the last assigned parameter that are assumed to have already been skipped,
// meaning that the runtime type of the next argument must not belong to `X`.

type CA0O0<X, R> = () => R;

type CA1O0<A1, X, R> = (a1: A1) => R;
type CA0O1<X, O1, R> = CA1O0<Exclude<O1, X>, never, R> & CA0O0<X | O1, R>;

type CA2O0<A1, A2, X, R> = (a1: A1, a2: A2) => R;
type CA1O1<A1, X, O1, R> = CA2O0<A1, Exclude<O1, X>, never, R> & CA1O0<A1, X | O1, R>;
type CA0O2<X, O1, O2, R> = CA1O1<Exclude<O1, X>, never, O2, R> & CA0O1<X | O1, O2, R>;

type CA3O0<A1, A2, A3, X, R> = (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3) => R;
type CA2O1<A1, A2, X, O1, R> = CA3O0<A1, A2, Exclude<O1, X>, never, R> & CA2O0<A1, A2, X | O1, R>;
type CA1O2<A1, X, O1, O2, R> = CA2O1<A1, Exclude<O1, X>, never, O2, R> & CA1O1<A1, X | O1, O2, R>;
type CA0O3<X, O1, O2, O3, R> = CA1O2<Exclude<O1, X>, never, O2, O3, R> & CA0O2<X | O1, O2, O3, R>;

function someFunction(arg1?: number, arg2?: string, arg3?: string|string[]) { }

const wrappedFunction: CA0O3<never, number, string, string | string[], void> = function() { 
  const normalizedArgs = args(arguments, [
    args.number(undefined), 
    args.string(undefined),
    args.oneOf([
      args.array,
      args.string
    ], undefined)
  ]);
  return someFunction(...normalizedArgs);
};
```

Of course, you lose the parameter names.  If you wanted to keep them, you'd have to write a script to generate the overload signatures.